# Better JPG or BMP?

Tags: c#, winforms

This might be a stupid question, but I'm curious.

I'm creating a game where I'm going to need a lot of images. Now I want to know which format is better to use? JPG or BMP? Which uses more memory, or which format will the program process faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Bitmap

The tradeoff here is speed vs disk space.

- Bitmap is fast to use as it does not need decompressing but big on disk and memory
- Jpeg is small on disk/memory but slighly slower to load. You may also suffer compression artifacts.

If I was going to use a compressed format, i would use png as it is lossless.

*EDIT: after decompression Jpeg will use roughly the same memory as a bitmap.*

Comment: Thanks for you explanation :). Going to mark it as an accepted answer, just need to wait countdown.

Comment: _"You may also suffer compression artifacts"_ - that depends on the source and how you save the image. _"If I was going to use a compressed format, i would use png as it is lossless"_ - that recommendation cannot be made if you don't know the source. If OP wants to use photos, PNG is not the most obvious choice.

Comment: @Gusdor seen any games in WinForms recently? Point is you can't just recommend _"use png as it is lossless"_, as that is not the only criterion for choosing an image format.

Comment: Are you sure that jpeg is small on memory ? i don't think jpeg sits in the memory in his compressed format, I think it sits there decompressed, otherwise every time you will draw on the screen the program would have to decompress the image...

Comment: @OopsUser arguably, when it is decompressed, it is no longer a jpg. The distinction is important though. Thanks for raising the issue.

Answer (score 5):

From my experience of game developing you would probably want to use PNG.

- PNG is compressed
- PNG is losseless
- And the most important part, PNG has opacity.. you need opacity because otherwise any character in the game that isn't square would have white corners (or other color that you will use as background).

Good luck with the game

Answer (score 1):

Please define *"a lot of images"*.

> Which uses more memory or which format will the program process faster?

It doesn't really matter, as an image has to be uncompressed anyway to do anything with it. The image format you use probably isn't going to be the bottleneck anyway if you're creating your game in WinForms.

Comment: BMP images are not compressed

Comment: @Thomas but a JPEG is, and in order to display it, it must be decompressed, resulting in at least equal memory use as a BMP of the same image.

Comment: @CodeCaster Are we bothered about memory use or file retrieval speed? OP specifically referenced speed.

Comment: @Gus I quoted the relevant text from the question in my answer, I do not see file retrieval speed there. OP asks _"which uses more memory"_, which I answered, and which format get _"processed faster"_ entirely depends on what kind of processing OP wants to perform.